# Run privileged podman without sudo (and without usernamespace)

Tags: containers, rhel7, podman

I installed podman on RHEL 7.6 and can run normal docker command with sudo

```
sudo podman run hello-world
```

Is there a way to run it without sudo, without using usernamespace (similar to adding your user to the `docker` group when using regular `docker` command)?

I understand that when run as a non-root user, podman uses usernamespace. But I am not able to enable/ setup suid on the machine (LDAP etc.)

Currently, when run as a non-root user, I get this

```
user namespaces are not enabled in /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces
ERRO[0000] cannot re-exec process
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're running Podman and you're not the root user and you're not using sudo, i.e. "rootless", then you or your administrator has to enable user namespaces on the system in order for it to work fully.  Only a very few commands such as "podman version" will work in a rootless environment without user namespaces being set up.

The error that you're seeing would have to be taken care of by someone with administrative privileges with a command like `sysctl user.max_user_namespaces=15000` which would enable 15,000 usernamespaces on the system.  In addition the shadows-utils package would need to be installed on the system and the /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid files would have to have entries like:

username:100000:65536

in each for each user wanting to have usernamespace enabled for them.

Comment: Thanks @tom-sweeny. Do you know if the setting up of usernamespaces could be integrated with LDAP?