# Can I run docker packaged software without root on podman/docker?

Tags: docker, podman, fenics

I've read that docker is not really meant as a way to package a program to deliver to end users, but this seems to be done a lot. There are various pieces of software that I would like to run that have only two alternatives: build from source, or docker. I have `podman` on my computer (redhat 7.7), but I don't have root access on my computer, and can't seem to get anything to run with `podman`. Is this something that can be easily set up by my admin (I would need to walk him through this) so I *can* run these packages?

For example, I download [FENICS](https://fenicsproject.org/download/), run the install script, then `fenicsproject run` and I get a password prompt: `Authentication is required to run programs as a non-logged-in user.` Alternately, I run the command (supplied on the downloads page)

```
podman run -ti -p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000 -v $(pwd):/home/fenics/shared -w /home/fenics/shared quay.io/fenicsproject/stable:current
```

and get the same password prompt, though after closing it I also get the error `user namespaces are not enabled in /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces`.

Comment: Isnt the main purpose of podman to allow non-root, daemonless docker execution? With the docker cli, you just need to be in the docker group: `sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)`

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56296932/run-privileged-podman-without-sudo-and-without-usernamespace

Comment: Also, I found instructions for (I think) setting up things to do what I want: https://podman.io/blogs/2019/10/29/podman-crun-f31.html but it looks like it requires podman > 1.6.2, so I'm guessing I'm out of luck